# SQL Server : two linked servers - same server, different database and login

Tags: sql-server

I need to be able to connect to 3 remote databases simultaneously from my local SQL Server instance using SQL Server 2008 R2. `Db1` and `Db2` are both on `Svr1` and `Db3` is on `Svr3`. Each database requires a different login to gain access. I want to write a script that has simultaneous access to all 3 databases.

I gave up trying to create these using `sp_addlinked` server (despite successful use of this in past projects) because I simply could not get any of the connections working. I did manage to set up working linked servers for access to `Db1` and `Db3` on `Svr1` and `Svr3` respectively, no problem, using SSMS (right click on Linked Servers, New Linked Server). However, I don't know how to set up the linked server for db2 - it will not allow me to set up 2 linked servers with the same name (understandably). When I try to set up one using a name that does not map to a known SQL Server instance (and so use a data source or provider string to connect), it won't work.

Can I do what I want to do using the SSMS method? Or is there a way I can use the same linked server for `Db1` and `Db2` but use different logins somehow?

Comment: I should have added that I can connect to Db2 fine when it is set up under the Svr1 linked server instead of Db1. So username, password etc have been proven.

Comment: Something you can do (only for testing purposes because it is an horrible solution), is to use the IP Address with one linked server and the server name for the other linked server. If you have control over your DNS, you can generate a CNAME for that server and use both connections by name.

Comment: Is DB2 on a different named instance or the same instance as DB1?

Comment: The IP address "fiddle" worked, thank you CrApHeR! I agree it's horrible and surely there must be a better solution but it has solved my problem. Thanks also Brad - same named instance.